# Keyboard mapping stuffed in terminal

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, terminal

I'm logging into a remote linux box:

```
 Linux lbox 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Wed May 18 23:13:22 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and my keyboard mapping seems to have gone down the drain.

```
up: ^[[A
down: ^[[B
right: ^[[C
left: ^[[D
tab: Real tab (doesn't do auto-completion)
```

What is happening?

Comment: How are you logging in?  What client?  What do you see from `echo $TERM`?  Have you tried running `reset`, or simply reconnecting?

Comment: Hi. I'm using gnome-terminal. echo $TERM returns xterm

Comment: I'm such a noob. I was in the C shell :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently I was automatically logged into /bin/sh instead of the bash shell

typing: bash brought me into the bash shell

```
> bash
```

Now looking into making bash my default shell

Comment: chsh -s /bin/bash myusername